# Having trouble with Android studio SDK manager

Tags: android-studio

I am very new to Android Studio, and don't come from a very technical background. This is baffling, as I've spend the majority of the last week working on fixing this... It's driving me crazy! The problem is, I live in Iran and due to the sanctions I don't have access to the dl.google stuff... Even with a VPN on, I get errors! And, This is what the SDK manager that I downloaded separately shows me:

[image: Can't post the image yet!]

There's nothing to download. Here's the SDK manager inside Android Studio :

[image]

It says "Partially Installed" but I don't know how to FULLY install them.

My main issue : This error :

![enter image description here][3]

> Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 19.1.0 Install Build Tools 19.1.0 and sync
>   project

Before that, I was getting other kinds of error. I have no idea how to fix this... Even my teacher has no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Your question is too broad and doesn't give us enough to go on.

Comment: @Difster Thanks for responding. I have no idea how to explain what's happening, because I don't even know what is happening. I've probably installed and uninstalled the program 10 times by now.

Comment: It's fine. Just had to do another uninstall, and do the whole thing with a VPN on. :(

Comment: Ha. Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you have not downloaded all the required sdk components necessary for building android application.

As you mentioned above, the simplest solution would be to do download the build-tool version 19.1.0 and then sync project but as you have mentioned that you can't download from https://dl.google.com due to firewall/dns issues..

So, I would suggest you to either use proxy settings in sdk manager to unblock and download the build-tools or you can also grab a pre-downloaded sdk with all components installed here (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9FT-4TSz8ukYnJWQ3hJUmYyQzA/view) and just replace the sdk directory with this one and reload. Nothing to download and you will be up and running.